# Simple WebRTC Example! But why it didn't work & what did I do wrong?

Tags: webrtc

I found this link on the internet which demonstrates how WebRTC works https://shanetully.com/2014/09/a-dead-simple-webrtc-example/

Its source code is here https://github.com/shanet/WebRTC-Example

Now, I am trying to follow the example and here what I did:

1- I created a folder name `voicechat`

2- I created 2 folders inside `voicechat`. That is `voicechat\client` & `voicechat\server`

3- I put the `index.html` &  `webrtc.js` into `voicechat\client`

4- I put `server.js` into `voicechat\server`

5- I put the folder `voicechat` into my Tomcat `webapps` folder. So The path will be like this `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.53\webapps\ROOT\voicechat`

6- I started my Tomcat.

7- I opened http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/voicechat/client/index.html in my PC & the webpage showed webcam (webcam 1) of my PC. No problem.

8- I opened http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/voicechat/client/index.html in another PC & the webpage also showed webcam (webcam 2) of other PC. But I could not see webcam 1 of my PC. And when I talked in my PC, the person sitting in other PC could not hear what I am talking and via versa.

**So, why it didn't work What did I do wrong?**

Here is the code of 3 files:

**index.html**

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="webrtc.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <video id="localVideo" autoplay muted style="width:40%;"></video>
        <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay style="width:40%;"></video>

        <br />

        <input type="button" id="start" onclick="start(true)" value="Start Video"></input>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            pageReady();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**webrtc.js**

```
    var localVideo;
var remoteVideo;
var peerConnection;
var peerConnectionConfig = {'iceServers': [{'url': 'stun:stun.services.mozilla.com'}, {'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}]};

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
window.RTCIceCandidate = window.RTCIceCandidate || window.mozRTCIceCandidate || window.webkitRTCIceCandidate;
window.RTCSessionDescription = window.RTCSessionDescription || window.mozRTCSessionDescription || window.webkitRTCSessionDescription;

function pageReady() {
    localVideo = document.getElementById('localVideo');
    remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');

    serverConnection = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:3434');
    serverConnection.onmessage = gotMessageFromServer;

    var constraints = {
        video: true,
        audio: true,
    };

    if(navigator.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, getUserMediaSuccess, errorHandler);
    } else {
        alert('Your browser does not support getUserMedia API');
    }
}

function getUserMediaSuccess(stream) {
    localStream = stream;
    localVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
}

function start(isCaller) {
    peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(peerConnectionConfig);
    peerConnection.onicecandidate = gotIceCandidate;
    peerConnection.onaddstream = gotRemoteStream;
    peerConnection.addStream(localStream);

    if(isCaller) {
        peerConnection.createOffer(gotDescription, errorHandler);
    }
}

function gotMessageFromServer(message) {
    if(!peerConnection) start(false);

    var signal = JSON.parse(message.data);
    if(signal.sdp) {
        peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(signal.sdp), function() {
            peerConnection.createAnswer(gotDescription, errorHandler);
        }, errorHandler);
    } else if(signal.ice) {
        peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(signal.ice));
    }
}

function gotIceCandidate(event) {
    if(event.candidate != null) {
        serverConnection.send(JSON.stringify({'ice': event.candidate}));
    }
}

function gotDescription(description) {
    console.log('got description');
    peerConnection.setLocalDescription(description, function () {
        serverConnection.send(JSON.stringify({'sdp': description}));
    }, function() {console.log('set description error')});
}

function gotRemoteStream(event) {
    console.log('got remote stream');
    remoteVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
}

function errorHandler(error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

---

**server.js**

```
 var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;

var wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 3434});

wss.broadcast = function(data) {
    for(var i in this.clients) {
        this.clients[i].send(data);
    }
};

wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
        wss.broadcast(message);
    });
});
```

Comment: Tomcat is for java, not javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

server.js is intended to be run as a node server for websocket signaling. Run it with `node server.js`. You shouldn't need Tomcat at all.

From the project readme:

> The signaling server uses Node.js and ws and can be started as such:

```
$ npm install ws
$ node server/server.js
```

> With the client running, open client/index.html in a recent version of either Firefox or Chrome.

You can open index.html with just a file URL.

Comment: Why the downvote? I answered the question exactly. You're trying to use multiple open source projects based on node servers, and use them with a completely different web server.

Comment: I ran "npm install ws" and got an error like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/r38IO.png. Could you please tell me why? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I changed HTTPS_PORT = 8443 to HTTP_PORT = 8443. Do same with all the https; change it to http. Next, have only const serverConfig = { }; as the serverConfig and delete serverConfig  in const httpServer = http.createServer(handleRequest); After these changes, u can now run your server with npm start.

Answer (score -1):

This is the ultimate simple code can do the job. No need to install Node.js. Why need to install `Node.js`?

AND put that code into `index.html` file and start your webhost, then you done!

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//simplewebrtc.com/latest.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="localVideo" muted></div>
<div id="remoteVideo"></div>


<script>
var webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
    localVideoEl: 'localVideo',
    remoteVideosEl: 'remoteVideo',
    autoRequestMedia: true
});

webrtc.on('readyToCall', function () {
    webrtc.joinRoom('My room name');
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: SimpleWebRTC is a different library but has the same requirement - it uses a small node server for signaling. You can use the sandbox server configured by default for development, but when you deploy an application, you'll need to run your own signaling server.

Comment: @xdumaine, What do you mean?  I do not install any node server. I just run my tomcat server and then open the localhost/index.html and it works fine. I don't know what is node server. Just put the html file about in my Tomcat server then I can use WebRTC. Why do I need signaling Server?

Comment: When you use SimpleWebRTC without providing your own node signaling server, you're using their sandbox server for development. See the notes [on simplewebrtc.com](https://simplewebrtc.com/) about the signaling server. Your index.html page is opening a websocket to `wss://signaling.simplewebrtc.com/socket.io/` which is a node signaling server.

Comment: I have just installled the node.js. Then I opened "node.js", then type > node server.js--? SyyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. Then I run >npm install ws--> then I got error npm should be run outside of the node repl, in your normal shell. What wrong?

Comment: I don't understand. I want to incoporate Webrtc into my Java webapp. So, I have to run 2 server at the same time. Tomcat server for Java web and node server for webrtc? Why made things so complicated?

Comment: You don't *have* to use node, but if you want to use java, you'll have to implement the websocket connection and signaling functionality provided in those examples.

Comment: Ok, after running node server.js, I opened "http://localhost:2013" and saw a blank page. So I assumed that my signaling server is running. Then, in the http://simplewebrtc.com/latest.js, I changed "https://signaling.simplewebrtc.com:443/" to "http://localhost:2013". Then started tomcat, then run 2 "localhost/index.html" 1 in FIrefox and 1 in Chrome but it did not work. But if I change back to "https://signaling.simplewebrtc.com:443/", then it works ok. So Why did it happen?

Comment: SimpleWebRTC doesn't work with the example you originally linked in your question. You need to read documentation. I can't help you if you don't do some basic reading on the docs for each project.